# NullPointerException in handleOnGetSentenceSuggestionsMultiple (SpellCheckerSession)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I got the following exception reported several times in my ACRA reports. It seems to be coming only from devices running Android 4.4.2 but I have no idea where could be the problem.

Did anyone already meet this problem?

Thank you

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession.handleOnGetSentenceSuggestionsMultiple(SpellCheckerSession.java:222)
at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession.access$100(SpellCheckerSession.java:86)
at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$1.handleMessage(SpellCheckerSession.java:116)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**UPDATE**

There is this thread running: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161400

Developers on the thread have the exact same problem, on devices running Android 4.4.2 only. It seems to be fixed on the other versions.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074817/nullpointerexception-at-suggestionspan Try the answer over there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I actually checked this one already, but after reviewing the code I did not see any relationship between my problem and the locale configuration. I will maybe give it a try just in case.

Comment: I just checked my code, I am actually already preventing this problem (config.locale is null), it confirms it is not related to this issue.

Comment: Yeah, I would try it out just in case. That stacktrace isn't very helpful. I tried tracking it down and possibly the msg.obj is null? https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-release/core/java/android/view/textservice/SpellCheckerSession.java#116

Comment: Wait, you said "config.local is null". Did you mean to type is "not" null? Do you have a device that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I mean I actually assign a value to config.locale before using it since I allow my users to choose a language, so it cannot be null. I don't have a device with 4.4.2, I think the bug has been fixed but there does not seem to be any workaround for the 4.4.2 version.

Comment: Well, without seeing your code, it's hard to be specific, but looking at the source, it seems to indicate that your `SpellCheckerSessionListener` is null. What object do you have implementing that interface?

Comment: I did not put code simply because I have no idea where the bug comes from. I never call `SpellCheckerSessionListener`, I searched in my whole workspace... (same for `SpellCheckerSession`)

Comment: Ah, now I see why this is confusing. Are you using any libraries that may be invoking a SpellCheckerSession? Could you give us an outline of what your app does?

Comment: Not from the library I think, it seems related to the EditText, when the spell checking is available. I checked the code on the latest Android version and the line of the crash changed so I guess the class has been modified since 4.4.2. FYI, my app is an advanced diary, where a main EditText is needed (where the bug might come from).

Comment: I'm not quite following. "...when the spell checking is available." - Are you saying you _are_ using spell check? Also, the line number is kind of irrelevant, as the `handleOnGetSentenceSuggestionsMultiple()` method (where the Exception is happening) only has one line in it.

Comment: I am not calling it, I just mean I think it is used by default on the `EditText` views, the corrections/suggestions displayed during the input. It might be a soft keyboard related problem...

Comment: That's a thought. You might try `inputType="textNoSuggestions"` on the EditText. I'm not sure how you'd test that, though. It sounds like it's not happened on one of your own devices.

Comment: Was this issue ever solved? I'm encountering the exact same error now.
Not sure which edit text is the cause. Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: It seems to only happen on Android 4.4.2, same for me: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=161400

Comment: Look like bug in custom keyboard. `new SpellCheckerSession` has only in one place: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/7de7e0b0dd61acba813dec3a07d29f1d62026470/core/java/android/view/textservice/TextServicesManager.java#L172 but before has check on `if (listener == null)` then it can not be called from there. Then it custom keyboard with own call to `new SpellCheckerSession`.

Answer (score 2):

What work for me is

```
_editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

you can do this in xml file like

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

I thing by default this flag is true thats why it give this exception if give below 23 android version ,abouve 23 work fine

This is not the answer but until someone give answer to this question we can use above shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Turn off suggestions like this:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

works better than just:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```